# Dojo class and static function

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I have this class named `Test`

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare"
], function (declare) {
  var ctrl = declare(null, {

    fields : "field1,field2",
    constructor: function () {

    },
    checkFields : function(){
    }

  });

  ctrl.testStatic = function () {
    console.log(fields);// null
    console.log(this.fields);// null
  }
  return ctrl;
});

require(["my/Test"], function(Test){
  Test.testStatic();
});
```

Is is possible to have access to my field properties in my class Test ?

What's the best way to resolve this problem ?

Thanks for your help .

Comment: Have you tried `lang.hitch()` ?

Comment: where and how ? I don't see ....

Answer (score 2):

**First thing**  :

is why declaring function outside the declare block :

```
ctrl.testStatic = function () {
    console.log(fields); 
    console.log(this.fields);  
}
```

if you declare it inside the declare  it gonna work nicely

**Second thing :**

When requiring your Test class , think to instantiate this last , and  then access its methods like below :

```
require(["my/Test"], function(Test){
  var test = new Test()
  test.testStatic();
});
```

See below snippet (could not recreate in separate file here !!) :

```js
require([
  "dojo/_base/declare"
], function(declare) {
  // updated as Gibbok correction (capitalize)
  var Ctrl = declare(null, {
    fields : "field1,field2",
    constructor: function () {
      
    },
    checkFields : function(){
      
    },
    testStatic : function() {
      console.log(this.fields);// null
    }
  });
  
  var ctrl1 = new Ctrl();
  ctrl1.testStatic();

});
```

```html
<script>
  window.dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: false,
    async: true
  };
</script>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

---

Otherwise , If you want to use a class as static object , (access without using new keyword ) . 
It's usless to use the dojo declare classy , so the declaration should be like :

```
define([], function () {
  var ctrl = {
    fields : "field1,field2",
    constructor: function () {

    },
    checkFields : function(){

    },
    testStatic : function() {
        //console.log( fields ) this will fail fields is not defined reference error
        console.log(this.fields);
    }
  };

  return ctrl;
});
```

then the expected output of

```
require(["my/Test"], function(Test){
  Test.testStatic();
});
```

would be :

> field1,field2

Comment: I don't want to create a new instance as above (dont' have new ctrl())

Comment: still not usful :) !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the property `fields` as static @bRIMOs answer is a valid one.

If instead you want the property `fields` as **non** static, means you want to add a property `fields` for each instance of `Ctrl`, you should populate the `fields` property directly in the `constructor`. Otherwise changes in `fields` will be reflected in all your instances of `Ctrl`, this is valid only if the property is NOT a primitive type.

In addition to the good answer from @bRIMOs, I would add:

- Use a dojo convention for class name using uppercase for the initial letter `Ctrl`.

Revised snippet using non static member:

```js
require([
  "dojo/_base/declare"
], function(declare) {

  var Ctrl = declare(null, {
    constructor: function () {
        // NOTES! property is declared in the constructor
        this.fields = "field1,field2";
    },
    checkFields : function(){     
    },
    testStatic : function() {
      console.log(this.fields);
    }
  });
  
  var ctrl1 = new Ctrl(); 
  ctrl1.testStatic(); // field1,field2

  var ctrl2 = new Ctrl(); 
  ctrl2.fields = 'xyz';
  ctrl2.testStatic(); // xyz

  ctrl1.testStatic(); // field1,field2
});
```

```html
<script>
  window.dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: false,
    async: true
  };
</script>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great , just to add some point , I dont know if you agree with me , but as a field here is primitive type  (string) so  whether  you created in constructor , or declare it in the scope of the object (class) it'll be unique for all instance not reflected ( because primitive is going to get copied in memory for each instance ) exept a non primitive type that will be unique for all instance in global scope (not in constructor) so  it is referenced in memory for alla instance and not copied like Array, Object .... , I by the way thnx for correction and explanation :) thumbs

Comment: what i've suggested to the lg0173 is to created an object with define without declare so it'll return an object with static fields .

Comment: @bRIMOs thanks for your comment, I made an edit to my answer to make it more clear regarding primitive and non primitive. I also add a +1 to your answer which I like :). Thanks for time.

Comment: great explanation, I appreciate :) thank you too :) .